# Undefined index: post in miniblog

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I have searched around and can't figure this issue out.

```
$post   = (string) mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['post']);<br>
$page   = (int) mysql_real_escape_string(intval($_GET['page']));
```

I don't understand what the error `undefined index:post` means. I get this error for both the `$post` and `$page` lines.

Comment: Is 'post' a valid get parameter? When you are performing your GET request, is there a '?post=something' appended to the URL?

Answer (score 1):

The [$_GET variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) will be populated only if your URL has a query string (that usually means a form was submitted with the GET method).
So you must first check if `$_GET` contains values, then use theses values:

```
if(isset($_GET['post']) && isset($_GET['page'))
{
    $post   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['post']);
    $page   = intval($_GET['page']);
}
```

Casting to `string` is useless in your first line of code: `mysqli_real_escape_string` returns a string anyway.
In your second line of code:

- using `mysql_real_escape_string` since you are using `intval`: an integer value does not need any extra escaping
- casting to `int` is useless, this was already done with `intval`

## Important notice:

Since all mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of PHP, you should use [MySQLi or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) (I used MySQLi in my code sample).

Answer (score 0):

This error means exactly what the warning is telling you.

$_GET is an array of items passed in as HTTP GET parameters.

`$_GET['page']` and `$_GET['post']` are giving you undefined index warnings because there is no item in the associative array with the key 'post' or 'page'.

One way to figure out what is going on is to var_dump() the entire $_GET array to see what's in it.

`var_dump($_GET)`